# What form is this equation $Z1 = r^2(\sin (\theta) + i\cos(\theta))$?

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, complex-numbers, polar-coordinates

Is it supposed to be triangular or what exactly?

$Z1 = \sin (\pi / 3) + i\cos(\pi / 3)$

It's a complex number btw. $r = 1$ and $\theta = \pi / 3$ btw.

Just asking. I didn't see an equation like that before. I knew how to convert it to the Rectangular. Just asking.

Comment: This reminds me of the time a classmate in multivariable calculus lecture raised their hand and asked, "so we have partial derivatives...can we take partial...integrals?" The professor ignored the question and moved on because this was not math, it was just playing with words. That's kind of what's going on here. I will give you an answer though, that form of a complex number is usually called polar.

Comment: @NinadMunshi but $cos \theta$ is multiplied by i, not sin \theta. Yeah, I know this is a very stupid question. I was just taken by it. As I said, I knew how to convert it to its other forms. I just got confused by the form at first.

Comment: I see your point, but polar is polar, even if it is not "standard".

Comment: @MPW I know. I said that I converted it.

Comment: @NinadMunshi So you are saying that, in this case, $ cos (\theta) = sin (\pi/3) $ and $ sin (\theta) = cos (\pi/3) $ ...right?

Comment: I mean while that's true (since $\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta\right) = \cos\theta$ and vice versa) what I was actually saying that calling the "standard" $\cos\theta + i\sin\theta$ "the" exclusive polar isn't always true. $\sin\theta + i\cos\theta$ is also a "polar" form even if it is not "the" polar form.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of $\sin (\pi / 3) + i\cos(\pi / 3)$ as already in rectangular form.  The real part is $\sin(\pi/3) = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ and the imaginary part is $\cos(\pi/3) = \frac{1}{2}$.

**Aside**
$\sin (\pi / 3) + i\cos(\pi / 3)$ is not polar form with modulus $r=1$ and argument $\theta  = \pi/3$.  That would be $\cos (\pi / 3) + i\sin(\pi / 3)$.

Comment: Yep. Like I thought. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

That's not an equation, that is, as you said, a complex number. There's nothing to solve.

Comment: I didn't tell anyone to solve it. I think you misunderstood my question. I was just asking about the form(I know, it's a stupid question)

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't understood. It is called polar form (or trigonometric form).